# Trying to install python3 but terminal keeps showing as python 2.7.13

Tags: python, homebrew

I have 2.7.13 on macOS Sierra and I'm trying to upgrade to python3 via

```
brew install python3
```

everything seems to have went fine except the last part:

```
==> Installing python3 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python3-3.6.1.sierra.bottle
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring python3-3.6.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg instal
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg instal
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg instal
==> Caveats
Pip, setuptools, and wheel have been installed. To update them
  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

See: http://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1: 3,600 files, 55.8MB
```

after that I type

```
python
```

and I get

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 17 2016, 23:03:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm pretty new to coding so any help is appreciated!

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog it isn't the same O.S.

Answer (score 5):

Python 2.x and Python 3.x have different terminal commands.

Use command : `python3` to use python 3.x

Similarly, use `pip3` for installing python modules.

---

Note : Also try to learn [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) (virtual environments), so that you can keep your python 2.x and python 3.x environments separate.

There are many tutorials to do this, one such is [this tutorial](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/07/install-python3-on-mac-os-x-and-use-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper.html).